# Shorten (Limit) the length of a sentence

Tags: r, string, substring, trim

I have column of long names and I would like to cut these to max **40 characters** length.

Sample data:

```
x <- c("This is the longest sentence in world, so now just make it longer",
 "No in fact, this is the longest sentence in entire world, world, world, world, the whole world")
```

I would like to shorten the sentece length to about 40 (-/+ 3 nchar) so that I don't shorten the sentence in the middle of an word. (So the length is decised on empty space between words).

Also I would like to add **3 dots** after the shortened sentece.

The desired output would be something like this:

```
c("This is the longest sentence...","No in fact, this is the longest...")
```

This function would just blindly shorten at **40 char.**:

```
strtrim(x, 40)
```

Comment: have you tried putting a solution together yet?  `strsplit`, `nchar`, `cumsum`, and `substr` would be the components you need to use ...

Comment: Yes, I have tried various things non worked as expected. Actually, the decomposition of the sentece by strsplit is the way to go...

Comment: `strwrap(x, width = 40)`?

Comment: @akrun: your function doesn't take into account the length of sentence, just adds dots..or is that my part? :)

Comment: I get: `nchar(x)[1]`# [1] 71

Comment: @Max That is your original `x` variable.  I am mentioning about the one `str1` which is exactly `40` characters.

Comment: `body(utils:::str.default)[[11]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I have better solution now :)

```
x <- c("This is the longest sentence in world, so now just make it longer","No in fact, this is the longest sentence in entire world, world, world, world, the whole world")

extract <- function(x){
  result <- stri_extract_first_regex(x, "^.{0,40}( |$)")
  longer <- stri_length(x) > 40
  result[longer] <- stri_paste(result[longer], "...")
  result
}
extract(x)
## [1] "This is the longest sentence in world, ..."   "No in fact, this is the longest sentence ..."
```

Benchmarks new vs old (32 000 sentences):

```
microbenchmark(sapply(x, cutAndAddDots, USE.NAMES = FALSE), extract(x), times=5)
Unit: milliseconds
                                        expr        min         lq     median         uq      max neval
 sapply(x, cutAndAddDots, USE.NAMES = FALSE) 3762.51134 3762.92163 3767.87134 3776.03706 3788.139     5
                                  extract(x)   56.01727   57.18771   58.50321   79.55759   97.924     5
```

**OLD VERSION**

This solution requires `stringi` package and ALWAYS adds three dots `...` to the end of string.

```
require(stringi)
sapply(x, function(x) stri_paste(stri_wrap(x, 40)[1],"..."),USE.NAMES = FALSE)
## [1] "This is the longest sentence in world..." "No in fact, this is the longest..."
```

This one adds the three dots only to sentences which are longer than 40 characters:

```
require(stringi)
cutAndAddDots <- function(x){
  w <- stri_wrap(x, 40)
  if(length(w) > 1){
    stri_paste(w[1],"...")
  }else{
    w[1]
  }
}
sapply(x, cutAndAddDots, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
## [1] "This is the longest sentence in world" "No in fact, this is the longest..."
```

**PERFORMANCE NOTE**
Setting `normalize=FALSE` in `stri_wrap` may speed up this roughly 3 times (tested on 30 000 sentences)

Test data:

```
x <- stri_rand_lipsum(3000)
x <- unlist(stri_split_regex(x,"(?<=\\.) "))
head(x)
[1] "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel commodo in."                                                    
[2] "Ultricies mauris sapien lectus dignissim."                                                      
[3] "Id pellentesque semper turpis habitasse egestas rutrum ligula vulputate laoreet mollis id."     
[4] "Curabitur volutpat efficitur parturient nibh sociosqu, faucibus tellus, eleifend pretium, quis."
[5] "Feugiat vel mollis ultricies ut auctor."                                                        
[6] "Massa neque auctor lacus ridiculus."                                                            
stri_length(head(x))
[1] 43 41 90 95 39 35

cutAndAddDots <- function(x){
   w <- stri_wrap(x, 40, normalize = FALSE)
   if(length(w) > 1){
     stri_paste(w[1],"...")
   }else{
     w[1]
   }
 }
 cutAndAddDotsNormalize <- function(x){
   w <- stri_wrap(x, 40, normalize = TRUE)
   if(length(w) > 1){
     stri_paste(w[1],"...")
   }else{
     w[1]
   }
 }
 require(microbenchmark)
 microbenchmark(sapply(x, cutAndAddDots, USE.NAMES = FALSE),sapply(x, cutAndAddDotsNormalize, USE.NAMES = FALSE),times=3)
Unit: seconds
                                                 expr       min        lq    median        uq       max
          sapply(x, cutAndAddDots, USE.NAMES = FALSE)  3.917858  3.967411  4.016964  4.055571  4.094178
 sapply(x, cutAndAddDotsNormalize, USE.NAMES = FALSE) 13.493732 13.651451 13.809170 13.917854 14.026538
```

Comment: This solution would be fine, but I would need the dots just for the shortened senteces. Also I would need somewhat faster solution. So I would wait a bit. Thank you!

Comment: @akrun: if you say so... I believe you :)

Comment: @akrun; sure, your guess is enough too me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Base R solution:

```
baseR <- function(x){
  m <- regexpr("^.{0,40}( |$)", x)
  result <- regmatches(x,m)
  longer <- nchar(x)>40
  result[longer] <- paste(result[longer],"...",sep = "")
  result
}
baseR(x)==extract(x)
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

Works just like @bartektartanus `extract` :) But it's slower... I tested this on data generated from his code. Still, if you don't want to use any external packages - this one works!

```
microbenchmark(baseR(x), extract(x))
Unit: milliseconds
       expr       min       lq    median        uq      max neval
   baseR(x) 101.20905 107.0264 108.79086 111.03229 162.6375   100
 extract(x)  52.83951  54.6931  55.46628  59.37808 103.0631   100
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured I'd post this one too.  Definitely not `stringi` speed, but it's not too shabby.  I needed one to bypass the print methods for `str` so I wrote this.

```
charTrunc <- function(x, width, end = " ...") {
    ncw <- nchar(x) >= width
    trm <- strtrim(x[ncw], width - nchar(end))
    trimmed <- gsub("\\s+$", "", trm)
    replace(x, ncw, paste0(trimmed, end))
}
```

Testing on the string from @bartektartanus answer:

```
x <- stri_rand_lipsum(3000)
x <- unlist(stri_split_regex(x,"(?<=\\.) "))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(charTrunc = {
    out <- charTrunc(x, 40L)
    },
    times = 3
)

Unit: milliseconds
      expr     min      lq     mean  median       uq      max neval
 charTrunc 506.553 510.988 513.4603 515.423 516.9139 518.4049     3

head(out)
# [1] "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, venenati ..."
# [2] "Tincidunt at pellentesque id sociosq ..."
# [3] "At etiam quis et mauris non tincidun ..."
# [4] "In viverra aenean nisl ex aliquam du ..."
# [5] "Dui mi mauris ac lacus sit hac."         
# [6] "Ultrices faucibus sed justo ridiculu ..."
```